# Can we post on Google plus from android application?

Tags: android, google-plus

How can we integrate our android apps for posting data on Google Plus Walls.
If any one know how to do this please provide me API and sample code for posting data
on google plus wall using android application.

Comment: You could use ACTION_SEND intents for that. However, the user would be able to choose something other than Google+ too...

Answer (score 6):

The [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) is currently read-only. It does not support write operations (like posting).

Comment: You can see all the calls at https://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=plus&_v=v1 this is read only.

Answer (score 3):

Refer this link , google provide API for google + in beta version using this you can post to google + ,

https://developers.google.com/+/downloads

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android

Comment: I didn't find any API to actually be able to post something on behalf of authenticated user.. can you point us?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/plus-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/plus/cmdline/PlusSample.java?repo=samples see this link

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/downloads/detail?name=google-plus-java-starter_v3.zip&can=2&q= you can download sampe project for google plus here

Comment: this project is only for post reading ,not for writing in wall