# Make a post on google+ : what's the current situation?

Tags: android, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we post on Google plus from android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485111/can-we-post-on-google-plus-from-android-application)

According to this post on stackoverflow
[Can we post on Google plus from android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485111/can-we-post-on-google-plus-from-android-application)

google+ 's APIs are read-only so I cannot post, anyway date refers to last year..did something changed?

I need a way to share a link in google+ 's wall, the same behaviour you can find on "google+ share" button on web sites, but on my app.

I cannot rely on webview as user could not be currently logged to google+'s account, and I'd prefer to not launch the intent for webbrowser: the best choice would definely be to use google+ api's to achieve this task...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(ShareActivity.this)
   .setText("This site has lots of great information about Android!
      http://www.android.com")
   .setType("text/plain")
   .getIntent()
   .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");

startActivity(shareIntent);
```

[Look at here](http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.in/2012/05/sharing-rich-content-from-your-android.html) for more details.

Comment: Sweet! Before digging in the doc I have a couple of questions: 1)From which android version can I use this? 2)What happens if I make this call when user has not a google+ account or is not currently logged in?3)Are other social networks like twitter or facebook supported as well?